# What should I do with a savings account in another country?

Tags: savings, france, switzerland

I live in Switzerland but I have a savings account in France (about 7000 Euros). I don't visit France very often and don't plan on living in the EU. I'm starting university next year but I am not in dire need of this money. What should I do with this money? Transfer it to my Swiss savings account?

Comment: [Related question](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/84400/35567)

Answer (score 4):

If the fees to keep the account open are reasonable then it's worth keeping it open for now.  It streamlines things if you need to visit or otherwise have business transactions (e.g. order things from online stores) with France or other EU countries.  If you are not yet even in university, I think it is far too early to predict where you will end up spending your time in life.